# Split excel based on row values into multiple csv files using pandas python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I want to split large excel file into multiple csv chunk files of a certain size (example 10 rows each), as below code:

```
# Function to split sheets
def split_xls_to_csv(file_location,chunk_size,dest_dir,archive_dir):
    curr_date = datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
    curr_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    file_name = os.path.basename(file_location) 
    try:
        logMessage(f"Processing file \'{file_name}\'.")
        batch = 0
        df = pd.read_excel(file_location)
        file_count = math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_size)
        for chunk in np.array_split(df, file_count):
            logMessage(f'Splitting file \'{file_name}\' ----> ({batch + 1} of {file_count})')
            o_filename = f'{file_name.replace(".xlsx","")}_{curr_date}_{curr_time}_{batch + 1}.csv'
            output_path = os.path.join(f'../{dest_dir}', o_filename)
            chunk.to_csv(output_path, index=False, header=True)
            batch += 1
        logMessage("Splitting file completed. !!!")
    except Exception as ex:
        logError("Exception: ")
```

The below image show the sample excel where I have set split to happen as 10rows each, that happens perfectly, but the catch is, if the 10th row and the next consecutive rows like 11, 12 row "documentNo" column value matches to 10th row "DocumentNo", then the split should happen from 13th row, not from 11th row.
In below eample split should happens from 13th row not from 11th row (chunk_size is set as 10)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening because the numbers in the Document No column are stored as text and not as numbers? There is a green mark towards the end indicating an error.
You can convert the strings in the column to numbers first and then execute your code which seems fine to me.